# Django, can't make User a foreign key

Tags: python, django

I've ran into problem with django models. Here is models file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Files(models.Model):
    bind_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.filename
```

And when I try to migrate , I get the following error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, login, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying login.0002_auto_20141009_0054...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 91, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 89, in render
    model=lookup_model,
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field login.Files.bind_user: auth.User
```

I've done everything as is written here

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
```

Django version is 1.7
Any ideas or suggestions ?
Thanks

Comment: Try to wrap `User` with quotation marks like this `bind_user = models.ForeignKey('User')`?

Comment: Try to use related_name in field definition, like this bind_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_files')

Comment: Didn't work.
ERRORS:
login.Files.bind_user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Comment: Also didn't work, the same error as before

Comment: did you run a `manage.py syncdb`? You need to set up auth tables first.

Comment: It shows the same problem

Comment: have you added `django.contrib.auth` in `INSTALLED_APPS` is `settings.py`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.conf import settings

...
bind_user = model.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
...
```

Note: AUTH_USER_MODEL will user default built-in django User model if you did not change AUTH_USER_MODEL setting.

Using AUTH_USER_MODEL is good generic way to create Foreign keys on a Model to your User Model.

Comment: I don't have AUTH_USER_MODEL setting, Isn't that used in older django versions ?

Comment: @user3156971 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#auth-user-model 
I don't think this setting was deprecated or smth. in 1.7 version. Maybe warning message in docs will help you.

Comment: @user3156971 It seems to me you have to update your django to newer. Look here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22485

Comment: I've updated django, but now the error is
raise ValueError(msg.format(field=operations[0][1], model=lookup_model))
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field login.Files.bind_user: auth.User